# Extracting part of a URL with no parameter using regex in JMeter

Tags: regex, jmeter

I'm creating a Jmeter test and need to extract part of a URL in a Response Body which has no parameter. I want to extract everything after `SIW_YMHD.start_url?`

I'm new to regex and am struggling to find an answer that fits as this has no parameter attached to it.

```
<input type="hidden" name="HREF.DUMMY.MENSYS.1" value="SIW_YMHD.start_url?2F1814C0553511E9Xa_3eK9p-F4k9fITqKhjwbNxiFwG2OGWSZh-continues......" />
```

Comment: You can use this regex: 'value="[^?]*\?([^"]*)' and then grap Group1, which will contaion what you want.

Comment: @PoulBak thanks for your reply. This seems to still contain ```SIW_YMHD.start_url?``` I need it to exclude that bit, how would i do this?

Comment: use `(?<=\?).*` and use the full match

Comment: JMeter does not support lookbehind ([ref](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)). Use the regex above and extract the group using `$1$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'value="[^?]*\?([^"]*)' looking for group $1$ worked. Thanks @PoulBak @horcrux

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to capture below highlighted string
SIW_YMHD.start_url?***2F1814C0553511E9Xa_3eK9p-F4k9fITqKhjwbNxiFwG2OGWSZh-continues......***"
If so, you can use Reg ex : **SIW_YMHD.start_url\?([^"]+)"**
I hope it will help you